# Grouping a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone please share how they approach grouping the following dataframe?
When I try to do this, I end up fiddling with groupbys, stacks and lambda functions but never quite get there. Its not readily apparent which methods and examples in the documentation are helpful for what I'm trying to do.

Does this stuff get more intuitive with experience? Appreciate any pointers or advice on how to choose and get more fluent with Pandas functions.

Here is the dummy data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[11,11,11,12,12,12],'B':[4,5,6,3,11,12]})

   A  B
0  11  4
1  11  5
2  11  6
3  12  3
4  12  11
5  12  12
```

I'd like to show that each of the original values in one column, is in a group with the values from the second column. (Duplicate 12 from second column removed in Group 2 below)

```
Group 1: [11,4,5,6,12] 
Group 2: [12,3,11]
```

And in the end, for the resulting dataframe to have the values from column A with the groups added as a list and numbered:

```
Col_A   Grouped_values  Group_name
11      [11,4,5,6,12]     Group 1
12      [12,3,11]         Group 2
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why `11` and `12` ended up in your list of `Group 1`. Could you clarify?

Comment: Without fully understanding the objective, have you tried something like `df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(set)`

Comment: The logic of the aggregation is not clear.

Comment: Grouped values are spurious in your expected output.

Comment: I agree, when I manually added the 12 to Group 1 I kind of broke the logic. But what I'm trying to do is to put the numbers in the two columns into groups. In row 4 of the original dataframe the 12 and 11 are together, so I want to make sure that that relationship is shown in both of the resulting groups. Does that clear it up a little bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC need convert values of `A` to `set`, then groupby and converted `B` values are added to `s` and cast back to `list`s, last add `Group_name` column:

```
s = set(list(df['A']))
print (s)
{11, 12}

df = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x) | s)).reset_index()
#thanks asongtoruin for better solution
df['Group_name'] = 'Group ' + (df.index + 1).astype(str)
print (df)
    A                  B Group_name
0  11  [12, 11, 4, 5, 6]     Group1
1  12        [11, 3, 12]     Group2
```

Comment: Why not `df['Group_name'] = 'Group ' + (groups.index + 1).astype(str)`?

Comment: @Kdog - Glad can help :)